# Hide Browse button after selecting an file

Tags: html, forms, file, input

I want to hide a "browse" button on a input file field after I have selected an image.

If you choose the image and there's a preview of this image I want to hide Browse button, is it possible?

Comment: there's a link to jsfiddle, what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/6340/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JQuery toggle like so:

```
$("#button").toggle();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9t2nvx9a/)

Note that I added an *id* to the button.

Comment: But another question - I want to add more input like this, but 2nd file input doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/9t2nvx9a/9/

Comment: [Here, i used class instead of id](http://jsfiddle.net/eq5jhjuw/).
Works for me :) If it resolves your problem, accept the answer so that it can help others. Thnx :)

Comment: Ok, this partly works, because when I choose img1 then it shows img1, but after I choose img2 then img1 disappear and in the same place there's only img2.

Comment: That happens because of this line of code: `$('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);`. The picture is always loaded in `#blah`, therefore when a new picture is loaded, it overwrites the previous one.

Comment: Can you help me how to solve this? How to make this work with multiple file inputs?